# Can the preposition “in” be omitted , in sentence, “you expect to rule the city the way you rule other city.”

Tags: grammaticality, prepositional-phrases, ellipsis

I have a question in below sentence.

> You expect to rule the city the way you rule other city.

I think the correct sentence is

> You expect to rule the city **in** the way you rule other city.

why can the preposition "in" be omitted?

if possible, the grammatical explanation is better for me to understand.

Comment: "You expect you to rule the city the way you rule other city" is a weird sentence. Maybe you meant "You expect to rule this city the way you ruled the other city"?

Comment: yes. I found the wrong expression at the moment. so I am gonna fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A noun phrase headed by *way* — that is, the noun *way* plus any adjectives, determiners, relative clauses, etc. — can be used adverbially. For example:

> He did it *the way she asked*.
>   *Either way,* we're out of time.
>   Look *both ways* before crossing the street.
>   She came in through the back door, and left *the same way*.

So although it's fine to use *in* in your example, it's also completely fine to leave it out. (Personally, I think it sounds better *without* the *in*.)

*Way* is rather unusual in this respect, but not absolutely unique. The same happens with many nouns relating to time:

> They go to church *every **week** that they're in town*.
>   She tried it *three **times*** before giving up.
>   He's moving away *next **month***.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ruakh! After posting this, No answer. so I checked up your answer today.

Comment: I forgot evaluating your answer. your explanation is what I exactly want. I'd like to thank you again !

Comment: @UtherKim: My pleasure!