# be expressed "a different way" or "in a different way"

Tags: prepositional-phrases, ellipsis

Following is excerpted from the book "The Language of Food" by Dan Jurafsky(page 7).

> Status used to be expressed a different way.

I am getting confused with this sentence.

As far as know, an object(a different way) can not follow a passive form expression(to be expressed). Meaningwise, "a different way" supposed to be "in a different way," a prepositional phrase.

So, "in" is omitted in this sentence? If so, is it because of the reason the previous post explained?(Link: [Can the preposition “in” be omitted , in sentence, “you expect to rule the city the way you rule other city.”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79034/can-the-preposition-in-be-omitted-in-sentence-you-expect-to-rule-the-city))

Comment: The author or editor made a mistake, and it should be "expressed ***in*** a different way".  It is possible to omit the "in" as a kind of *ellipsis* when speaking, but it sounds wrong to me when written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, sounds like a mistake. It needs "in". Author could also have used "conveyed in" as an alternative to "expressed"